# Applying function over entire parameter space/2d array, Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm in one of those weird places, where I know exactly what I want to do. I could easily code it up using for loops. but I'm trying to learn Numpy and I can't formulate how to solve this in Numpy.

I want to have a 2d array or parameter space. All values between 1200 and 1800, and all combinations therein. So [1200, 1200], [1200, 1201], [1200, 1202] .... [1201, 1200], [1201, 1201] etc.

I want to apply a function across this entire parameter space. The function uses a further 2 arrays, which are also values in 1200-1800 range. But they are random values, so these 2 extra arrays are random values in the 1200-1800 range, so [1356, 1689, 1436, ...] and [1768, 1495, 1358, ...] etc. check_array1 and check_array2.

The function needs to move through the parameter space checking a condition, which is basically `if x < check_array1 and y < check_array2 then 1 else 0`. Where x and y are the each specific point in the 2d parameter space. It needs to check against every value combination in the check arrays. Sum the total, do a comparison to another static value, and return the difference.

Each unique combination in the parameter space grid will then have a unique value associated with it based on how those specific x and y values from the parameter space compare to the 2 check arrays.

Hopefully the above makes, I just can't figure out how to work this into a Numpy friendly problem. Sorry for the wall of text.

Edit: I've written it in more basic Python to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
check1 = np.random.randint(1200, 1801, 300)
check2 = np.random.randint(1200, 1801, 300)

def check_this_double(i, j, check1, check2):
   total = 0
   for num in range(0, len(check1)):
       if ((i < check1[num]) or (j < check2[num])):
           total += 1           
   return total

outputs = {}
for i in range(1200, 1801):
   for j in range(1200, 1801):
    outputs[i,j] = check_this_double(i, j, check1, check2)
```

Edit 2: I believe I have it.
Following from Mountains code creating the p_space and then using np.vectorize on a normal Python fuction.

```
check1 = np.random.randint(1200, 1801, 300)
check2 = np.random.randint(1200, 1801, 300)

def calc(i, j):    
   total = np.where(np.logical_or(check1 < i, checks2 < j), 1, 0)
   return total.sum()

rate_calv_v = np.vectorize(rate_calc)

final = rate_calv_v(p_space[:, 0], p_space[:, 1])
```

Feels kind of like cheating :), there must be way to do it without np.vectorize. But this works for me I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the problem you are trying to solve.  I hope the following will 
give you a starting point on how numpy can be used.  I recommend going through a numpy introductory tutorial.

numpy boolean indexing and vector math can improve speed and reduce the need for loops. 
Here is my understanding of the first part of your questions.

```
import numpy as np

xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1200, 1801), np.arange(1200, 1801))
p_space = np.stack((xv, yv), axis=-1)  # the 2d array described

# print original values
print(p_space[0,:10,0])
print(p_space[0,-10:,0])

old_shape = p_space.shape
p_space = p_space.reshape(-1, 2)  # flatten the array for the compare

check1 = np.random.randint(1200, 1801, len(p_space))
check2 = np.random.randint(1200, 1801, len(p_space))

# you can used this to access and modify values that meet the condition
index_array = np.logical_and(p_space[:, 0] < check1, p_space[:, 1] < check2)

# do some sort of complex math
p_space[index_array] = p_space[index_array] / 2 + 10

# get the sum across the two columns
print(np.sum(p_space, axis=0))

p_space = p_space.reshape(old_shape)  # return to the grid shape

# print modified values
print(p_space[0,:10,0])  # likely to be changed based on checks
print(p_space[0,-10:,0])  # unlikely to be changed
```

Comment: This is exellent, very informative, thank you. Unfortunately it does not quite work. The check arrays are specific lengths I cannot change, unrelated to the size of the p_space array. Thus np.logical_and is failing. All 40000 p_space combinations need to be checked against each check array pair and summed.